# Final circle: Knights of the Round Table

Tags: java, initialization, final, circular-reference, circular-list

A friend of mine had a job interview. The question he was asked sounded like this:

> Is it possible to create a given number of similarly typed objects virtually arranged in a circle such that each of them contains two **final** references to its left (clockwise) and right (counterclockwise) neighbours?

If this seems too abstract to you, there was a more concrete interpretation. Think about the [Knights of the Round Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_of_the_Round_Table). Suppose King Arthur considers their union and arrangement at the table constant and inviolable. To express this idea, he created the following simplified model of a Knight at the Table:

```
public class Knight {
    private final String name;
    private final Knight leftNeighbour;
    private final Knight rightNeighbour;

    public final Knight getLeft() {
        return leftNeighbour;
    }

    public final Knight getRight() {
        return rightNeighbour;
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Note that all fields are final. Once set, they cannot be changed. The `name` field here merely illustrates individual properties of each object (there may also be other fields, final or not, but for the sake of simplicity, they are omitted). The primary interest here are the `leftNeighbour` and `rightNeighbour` fields. Being final, they "fasten" the circle making its structure immutable yet consisting of individual objects.

There is one problem, however. As you might have noticed, the above class outline lacks very important detail: **constructor(s)**. There must be a place where the final fields are assigned. To create constructor(s) - that was exactly the problem the interviewer proposed to solve - given the desired number of knights and their names in counterclockwise order, you should create corresponding objects and fill their fields. You may create as many constructors as you need and also may use instance initialization blocks and static factory methods, if you like, just don't touch the above lines. There should be at least one public constructor or a static factory method that returns one of the knights created. For example, the verification code below relies on the

```
public Knight(int knightCount, IntFunction<String> nameGenerator)
```

constructor, where `nameGenerator` of type `java.util.function.IntFunction<String>` is just a function that supplies a knight's name in response to its index. You may use an array of names instead, if you like.

My friend said that this is possible only via reflection - first create objects giving their `leftNeighbour` and `rightNeighbour` fields dumb values (e.g. `null`), then gain access to these fields and assign them meaningful values. But the interviewer said that the use of reflection, for the purpose of solving this problem, is prohibited. My friend concluded that the problem is unsolvable under such conditions. Indeed, to create a `Knight`, you need to know his neighbours first since it is not possible to assign a final field after exit from a constructor; but for this you need to know the neighbours of these neighbours including that very first `Knight` that has not yet been created - the chicken or the egg dilemma.

At first, I thought exactly the same. But after some thinking I come to the conclusion that the problem is not as hopeless as it appeared at the beginning. Could you provide a solution? You may use this verification code:

```
public static void testRoundTable(int size, IntFunction<String> nameGenerator,
            boolean printNames) {
    Knight k = new Knight(size, nameGenerator);
    Knight a = k;
    int c = 0;
    do {
        if (printNames)
            System.out.println(a);
        c++;
        a = a.getRight();
    } while (a != k);
    if (c != size)
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong knight count: " + c);
    if (printNames)
        System.out.println();
    a = k;
    c = 0;
    do {
        a = a.getLeft();
        if (printNames)
            System.out.println(a);
        c++;
    } while (a != k);
    if (c != size)
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong knight count: " + c);
    if (!printNames)
        System.out.println(c + " knights created");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testRoundTable(10, i -> "Knight #" + (i + 1), true);
    testRoundTable(20_000_000, i -> "Knight", false);
}
```

The output should be as follows:

```
Knight #1
Knight #2
Knight #3
Knight #4
Knight #5
Knight #6
Knight #7
Knight #8
Knight #9
Knight #10

Knight #10
Knight #9
Knight #8
Knight #7
Knight #6
Knight #5
Knight #4
Knight #3
Knight #2
Knight #1

20000000 knights created
```

Important notes:

- **Reflection** is strongly **prohibited**. It was either unknown at the time of King Arthur or considered blasphemous.
- The number of knights that you will be requested to create might be limited only by available memory, so be ready to create **very large tables** (e.g. with 20000000 knights, as above), without causing a stack overflow.

Here's my solution just for two knights:

```
public Knight(int knightCount, IntFunction<String> nameGenerator) {
    name = nameGenerator.apply(0);
    Knight other = new Knight(this, nameGenerator.apply(1));
    leftNeighbour = other;
    rightNeighbour = other;
}

private Knight(Knight mate, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    leftNeighbour = mate;
    rightNeighbour = mate;
}
```

This idea can be extended to the case of three, four and any other small number of knights. Each knight is responsible for creating the next one:

```
public Knight(int knightCount, IntFunction<String> nameGenerator) {
    name = nameGenerator.apply(0);
    Knight other = new Knight(1, knightCount, this, this, nameGenerator);
    rightNeighbour = other;
    for (int i = 1; i <= knightCount - 2; i++)
        other = other.rightNeighbour;
    leftNeighbour = other;
}

private Knight(int index, int knightCount, Knight first, Knight previous,
        IntFunction<String> nameGenerator) {
    name = nameGenerator.apply(index);
    leftNeighbour = previous;
    if (index == knightCount - 1)
        rightNeighbour = first;
    else
        rightNeighbour = new Knight(index + 1, knightCount, first, this, nameGenerator);
}
```

However, this implementation becomes increasingly difficult and would surely cause a stack overflow when the count reaches a million or so. On my computer, the "red line" is 5614.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Isn't the verification code enough for the summary of the work and the "chicken or the egg dilemma" paragraph enough for the description of the difficulty?

Comment: The verification code is not a summary of work. It is a way to check if the work is correct. The actual work is coming up with a suggested solution (what you thought the constructors should be), and an explanation of where it failed (e.g. the output of the verifier was not the output that you showed, there was an error, etc). As it stands, you're asking us to write those constructors for you.

Comment: You may want to move the question to [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). The site fits better for tricky tasks.

Comment: @akuzminykh I've thought about that. But the question is Java specific. The Java section is lean there. I think that the idiom of a final circle might be interesting for a more general Java audience (including practical applications).

Comment: @RealSkeptic I've added a solution that works for small numbers.

Comment: Are you allowed to use async activities?

Comment: @akuzminykh I believe so, but I don't know what you mean exactly. If you're going to use a separate thread for each knight, then the system will very soon refuse to create too many threads.

Comment: Your question looks much better now. Now, IMO, your solution is fine. If they said you are just limited by memory, that includes stack memory. Want more knights? Increase the stack size. I think the intention was to make sure you provide a solution that has no defined limits.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, but maybe there is a way make the most of **available** stack size? In real life, a programmer doesn't always have full control over the execution environment.

Comment: In real life, the `final` would be thrown out the window. Making it private and only accessible via getter would be enough, and save the whole trouble. Real life is different than code golf.

Comment: Is there any update on the question? Have you found another approach?

Comment: @akuzminykh No, not so far.